# What is the driving force for Claisen rearrangements?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic

[image]

I came across this mechanism (3,3 sigmatropic rearrangement). Why does the allyl vinyl ether have the ability to rearrange itself giving a new product? What drives the reaction?

Is it the instability of allyl vinyl ether (if yes, state why)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding up typical bond strengths. (Most of the bonds are the same, which saves some time.)

Answer (score 1):

The formation of the carbonyl group is a gain in thermodynamic stability over the vinyl ether. In your example, the monosubstituted alkene is a "wash". In any case, the alkyl substitution pattern of the non-enol ether double bond is not a problem.
The heat of this Claisen rearrangement, first conducted by Hurd and Pollack<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01275a051)</sup> in 1938, can be calculated by determining the heat of formation (ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup>) of allyl vinyl ether (**1**) and 5-hexenal (**2**). Heats of formation of allyl vinyl ether (**1**), hexanal (**3**), 1-hexene (**4**) and hexane (**5**) are known ([NIST](https://down.nist.gov/) and [Chemeo](https://www.chemeo.com/)). These heats of formation are shown in black. However, the ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup> of 5-hexenal (**2**) is not accessible in tables but it can be calculated. The heat of hydrogenation of monoalkyl substituted alkenes is ~125 kJ/mol (~30 kcal/mol). The reduction of 1-hexene (**4**) to hexane (**5**) is -124.6 kJ/mol, which is computed from the respective heats of formation of **4** and **5**. Applying this heat of hydrogenation to the reaction **2** ---> **3** gives a ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup> of -128.2 kJ/mol for 5-hexenal (**2**). Accordingly, the Claisen rearrangement of allyl vinyl ether (**1**) is exothermic by -100.6 kJ/mol.

[image]
1. [C. D. Hurd and M. A. Pollack, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1938**, *60*, 1905.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01275a051)